# how to implement Mediaplayer.OnPreparedlistener in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

i read the documentation
[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)
but still have no idea how to implement it in kotlin, i tried searching it on google but all answer is java so, how do i implement onpreparedlistener on kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

If you have read the `documentation`, you can provide example usage as follows.

There is one `override` method.

```
abstract void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
```

> Called when the media file is ready for playback.

***Sample UseCase***

```
private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
private var duration = 0

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(object : MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
                override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
                    duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration()
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared  $duration")
                    play()
                }
            })
```